# NSTask works in xcode run but not when i run it outside xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nstask

I have created this app that make use of the /usr/bin/say command in OS X.

This method takes the value from a textfield and uses "say" to save it.
But when i run this outside xcode. I don't get the saved file.

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender
{
    NSString *path;
    path = @"/usr/bin/say";

    NSArray *args;
    args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-o", @"text.wav", @"--data-format=LEF32@8000", [textField stringValue], nil];

    [[NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:path arguments:args] waitUntilExit];

    NSLog(@"Saved");
}
```

Anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it's being saved but you don't know where. The path *text.wav* is a partial path, so it's going to be saved in the "current directory". But what directory *is* the "current directory"? You probably don't know.

Comment: Shouldn't the current directory be Desktop if i run the app from Desktop?

Comment: But if i change the path to something like @"~/Desktop/text.wav" i get this error: Opening output file failed: prm?

Comment: Probably because the twiddle is not meaningful here. What if you give a complete absolute path starting with slash? Like this: /Users/yourname/Desktop/zork.wav

Comment: "Shouldn't the current directory be Desktop if i run the app from Desktop" That's my whole point. You're just making an assumption. I have no idea what the "current directory" will be under those circumstances. Therefore I presume that neither do you. So I'm suggesting maybe it would be better to make no assumptions in this regard.

Comment: And now don't forget to search your hard disk for all those "text.wav" files you saved without knowing where! :)